# Efficiently store a large sparse matrix (float)

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, sparse-matrix, pytables

I am looking for a solution to store about 10 million floating point (double precision) numbers of a sparse matrix. The matrix is actually a two-dimensional triangular matrix consisting of 1 million by 1 million elements. The element `(i,j)` is the actual score measure `score(i,j)` between the element `i` and element `j`. The storage method must allow very fast access to this information maybe by memory mapping the file containing the matrix. I certainly don't want to load all the file in memory.

```
class Score(IsDescription):
    grid_i = UInt32Col()
    grid_j = UInt32Col()
    score  = FloatCol()
```

I've tried `pytables` by using the `Score` class as exposed, but I cannot access directly to the element `i,j` without scanning all the rows. Any suggestion?

Comment: no experience with pyTables nor '(not so) big' data --  but is it possible / sufficient to map to a 1D index??

Comment: http://spyddles.blogspot.com/2008/06/sparse-module-in-scipy-is-useful-for.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 million double precision floats take up 80 MB of memory. If you store them in a 1 million x 1 million sparse matrix, in [CSR or CSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR_or_CRS.29) formats, you will need an additional 11 million int32s, for a total of around 125 MB. That's probably less than 7% of the physical memory in your system. And in my experience, on a system with 4GB running a 32-bit version of python, you rarely start having trouble allocating arrays until you try to get a hold of ten times that.

Run the following code on your computer:

```
for j in itertools.count(100) :
    try :
        a = np.empty((j * 10**6,), dtype='uint8`)
        print 'Allocated {0} MB of memory!'.format(j)
        del a
    except MemoryError:
        print 'Failed to allocate {0} MB of memory!'.format(j)
        break
```

And unless it fails to get you at least 4 times the amount calculated above, don't even hesitate about sticking the whole thing in memory using a `scipy.sparse` format.

I have no experience with pytables, nor much with numpy's `memmap` arrays. But it seems to me that either one of those will involve you coding the logic to handle the sparsity, something I would try to avoid unless impossible to.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`scipy.sparse`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html). [Here's](http://www.scipy.org/SciPyPackages/Sparse) some more info about the formats and usage.